# Enable Landscape rotation quick settings toggle on unrootable Moto G (maybe using ADB?)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, motorola-moto-g

Pretty much what the title says.  Apparently the Moto G only has Auto-Rotate and Portrait rotation locking allowed, and I was wondering if there was a way to enable Landscape rotation.  I know that there are some apps that can do the trick, but I thought I'd see if it was possible to get the native landscape lock working before I tried those.  I just upgraded to Lollipop.

I'm using a Republic Wireless phone, otherwise I'd definitely root the thing.  As it is, I don't really want to deal with the hassle.

Comment: Try `adb shell settings put system user_rotation 1`. Make sure auto-rotation is disabled. I'm not clear on what you finally want.

Comment: My quick settings orientation toggle only has two options—Portrait and Auto-Rotate.  I've heard that for some reason, the Landscape option is disabled on my model, and was looking for a way to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

This app can lock your screen in landscape: [Rotation Locker - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker&hl=en) and doesn't require root. I recommend this app because it has no permissions, is <100KB (no ads), and if you use Tasker, this app also has Tasker integration.

The explanation for your problem is that carriers and phone brands often decide "you don't need this feature" and just disable it on the front-end. But they don't actually spend the time to really disable that feature. The app works without root because Android provides an API to lock rotation, that's just part of Android.

Hope this helps solve your problem!

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Thanks!  Yeah, I know that the manufacturers will disable stuff like that.